# NSURL: Sending ø without URL encoding

Tags: ios, url, nsurlsession, nsurl

I'm using a third-party API in my app that expects `ø` to not be URL encoded. When I make an `NSURL` from it and send it with `NSURLSession`, it's escaped as `%C3%B8`.

Is there a way to whitelist additional characters, or disable auto-escaping completely? Unfortunately changing the API is out of my control.

Answer (score 0):

NSURL itself doesn't escape anything, so I have no idea what you're doing to create the NSURL object, but you're doing something wrong there.

With that said, NSURL's init method will probably return nil if you have bytes in the URL that are illegal in a URL, and it would not surprise me if it did so in this case, in which case the only workaround would be to use a third-party HTTP library like libcurl, and even that might not work.